# how to create creating circular seek-bar by canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to create a player seek bar in a circular shape. I must have two handles. one is for buffered part (grey colour in the picture) which is not draggle and on more item that is draggable and indicates the current part of the song that is playing. I am not sure how I can achieve this. Seems like canvas is the best option. But I am not sure if items will be draggable in canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 25;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
```

any idea or example how to achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Circle control**

This answer show how to create a game type control. It functions on a fixed interval and is rendered once every interval. It is not event driven, the mouse events do not call the control, the control simply checks the current mouse position. If the interval is lower than the mouse event interval some mouse movements will be lost but the control will work just as well.

This control can easily be adapted to be event driven by creating your own mouse event listeners and calling the `update` and `draw()` when needed. Warning though that this control uses the custom mouse object to change the cursor and to manage which control has ownership of the mouse. The mouse needs ownership so that when you drag one control handle over another you dont start dragging the other control. It works by setting the `mouse.mousePrivate` value to the controls unique ID the control will ignore the mouse if the `mouse.mousePrivate` is not equal to `0` (no owner) or the control's id

See the code for how it works. The demo displays several controls showing the differing behaviour. The centra control is a simple range control from 0 to 100, the top left one has 10 rotations and a range from 0 to 1000  and shows two position arcs to show the position. The top Right control has a floating value, that is if you are seeking a video the seek position does not respond immediately so the control has a floating value that shows the location arcs as the actual position while the number and dial handle shows the real position.

This is just an example and you should just take what you want. It has not been tested on more than a few browsers, nor has there been anything but the most fundamental testing so do not use it as is.

```js
demo = function(){

    /** fullScreenCanvas.js begin **/
    var canvas = (function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
        if(canvas !== null){
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
        // creates a blank image with 2d context
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
        canvas.id = "canv";    
        canvas.style.background = "#AAA";
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        return canvas;
    })();
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;

    /** fullScreenCanvas.js end **/
    /** MouseFull.js begin **/

    var canvasMouseCallBack = undefined;  // if needed
    var mouse = (function(){
        function cursorControl(cursor){
            if(cursor !== this.lastCursor){
                if(cursor !== "default"){
                    this.lastCursor = cursor;
                }
            }
        }
        function update(){
            if(this.element !== undefined){
                this.element.style.cursor = this.lastCursor;
                this.lastCursor = "default";
            }
        }
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false,
            interfaceId : 1, buttonLastRaw : 0,  buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,  // mouse is over the element
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
            getInterfaceId : function () { return this.interfaceId++; }, // For UI functions
            mousePrivate : 0,  
            lastCursor: "default",
            setCursor : cursorControl,
            frameEnd : update,
            startMouse:undefined,
            element : undefined,
        };
        function mouseMove(e) {
            var t = e.type, m = mouse;
            m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
            if (m.x === undefined) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
            m.alt = e.altKey;m.shift = e.shiftKey;m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
            if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail;}
            if (canvasMouseCallBack) { canvasMouseCallBack(m.x, m.y); }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        function startMouse(element){
            if(element === undefined){
                element = document;
            }
            mouse.element = element;
            "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",").forEach(
            function(n){element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);});
            element.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
        }
        mouse.mouseStart = startMouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    if(typeof canvas !== "undefined"){
        mouse.mouseStart(canvas);
    }else{
        mouse.mouseStart();
    }
    /** MouseFull.js end **/
    /** ImageTools.js begin **/
    var imageTools = (function(){
        var iT = {
            canvas:function(w,h){var c=document.createElement("canvas");c.width=w;c.height=h;return c;},
            createImage:function(w,h){var i=iT.canvas(w,h);i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");return i;},        
            loadImage:function(url,cb){var i=new Image();i.src=url;i.addEventListener('load',cb);return i;},
            image2Canvas:function(ig){var i=iT.canvas(ig.width,ig.height);i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");i.drawImage(ig,0,0);return i;},
            imageData:function(img){return (img.ctx||(iT.image2Canvas(img).ctx)).getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height).data;},
            saveAsPNG:function(image,filename){ // No IE <11 support. Chrome URL bug for large files may crash
                var ac,e;
                if(image.toDataURL === undefined){ image = it.image2Canvas(image);}
                ac = document.createElement('a'); ac.href = image.toDataURL(); ac.download = filename+".png";
                // need to update this as it has depreciated.
                if (document.createEvent) { 
                    (e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents")).initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,false, 0, null);
                    ac.dispatchEvent(e);
                }       
            }
        };
        return iT;
    })();

    /** ImageTools.js end **/

    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    var ix = Math.ceil(Math.min(w, h) / 20);
    const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;



    // following three function are for drawing, updating, and on to set floating value

    // draw circular control needs to be bound to a circular control object 
    function drawCirControl(){
        var c, r, r1, r2, x, y, w, a;
        c = this.ctx;
        r = this.radius1;
        r1 = this.radius2;
        
        c.lineWidth = w = Math.abs(r - r1);
        r2 = Math.min(r, r1) + w / 2;
        c.strokeStyle = this.borderColour;
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, r2, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        c.stroke();
        c.strokeStyle = this.colour;
        c.lineWidth = w - this.border * 2;
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, r2, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        c.stroke();
        // if more than one turn between min and max then also display progress as one turn
        if(Math.abs(this.startAng - this.endAng) > PI2){
            c.lineCap = "round";
            c.strokeStyle = this.lineColour;
            c.lineWidth = (w - this.border * 6)/2;
            c.beginPath();
            a = (this.floatingRaw - this.startAng) % PI2 + this.startAng;
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, r2 + (w - this.border * 6)/4, this.startAng, a)
            c.stroke();
            
            a = this.startAng + ((this.floatingValue - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * PI2;
            c.lineCap = "round";
            c.strokeStyle = this.lineInnerColour;
            c.lineWidth = (w - this.border * 6)/2;
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, r2 - (w - this.border * 6)/4, this.startAng, a)
            c.stroke();
            
            
        }else{
            c.lineCap = "round";
            c.strokeStyle = this.lineColour;
            c.lineWidth = w - this.border * 6;
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, r2, this.startAng, this.floatingRaw)
            c.stroke();
        }
        
        
        x = Math.cos(this.raw) * r2 + this.x;
        y = Math.sin(this.raw) * r2 + this.y;
        
        c.lineWidth = this.border;
        c.strokeStyle = this.borderColour;
        c.fillStyle = this.colour;
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(x, y, (w * this.handleSize)/2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        c.fill();
        c.stroke();
        
        c.font = this.font;
        c.textAlign = "center";
        c.textBaseline = "middle";
        c.fillText(Math.round(this.value), this.x, this.y);
    }

    // Update by checking mouse position and setting cursor and controling the dragging 
    // circular control needs to be bound to a circular control object 
    function updateCircularControl(){
        var r, r1, r2, x, y, dist, ang, a, w, h, mouseOver;
        r = this.radius1;
        r1 = this.radius2;
        w = Math.abs(r - r1);
        r2 = Math.min(r, r1) + w / 2;
        if(!this.floating){
            this.floatingValue = this.value;
        }
        this.raw = (this.value / (this.max - this.min)) * (this.endAng - this.startAng) + this.startAng;
        this.floatingRaw = (this.floatingValue / (this.max - this.min)) * (this.endAng - this.startAng) + this.startAng;
        x = Math.cos(this.raw) * r2 + this.x;
        y = Math.sin(this.raw) * r2 + this.y;
        mouseOver = false;
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - mouse.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - mouse.y, 2));
        if(this.mouse.mousePrivate === 0 || this.mouse.mousePrivate === this.id){
            if(dist < w * this.handleSize || this.dragging){
                this.mouse.setCursor("pointer");
                mouseOver = true;
                this.mouse.mousePrivate = this.id;
                if((this.mouse.buttonRaw & 1) === 1 && !this.dragging){
                    this.dragging = true;
                        this.lastAng = (this.raw + PI2) % PI2;
                    
                }else{
                    if((this.mouse.buttonRaw & 1) === 0){
                        this.dragging = false;
                    }else{
                        // get the angle to the mouse
                        ang = ((Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x)) + PI2) % PI2;
                        // get the delta from last angle
                        a = (ang - this.lastAng);
                        // check that is has not cycled and adjust acordingly
                        if(a < -Math.PI * (3/2)){
                            a += PI2
                        }
                        if(a > Math.PI * (3/2)){
                            a -= PI2
                        }
                        // set last angle
                        this.lastAng = ang;
                        // set the raw vale
                        this.raw += a;
                        this.value =  ((this.raw - this.startAng) / (this.endAng - this.startAng)) * (this.max - this.min) + this.min
                        this.value = Math.min(this.max, Math.max(this.min, this.value));
                        if(!this.floating){
                            this.floatingValue = this.value;
                        }
                        // recalculate the raw value
                        this.raw = (this.value / (this.max - this.min)) * (this.endAng - this.startAng) + this.startAng;
                        this.floatingRaw = (this.floatingValue / (this.max - this.min)) * (this.endAng - this.startAng) + this.startAng;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(! mouseOver && this.mouse.mousePrivate === this.id ){
            this.mouse.mousePrivate = 0;
        }
    }
    // set circular control floating value needs to be bound to a circular control object 

    function setCirciularFloatingValue(v){
        this.floatingValue = v;
        this.floatingRaw = (this.floatingValue / (this.max - this.min)) * (this.endAng - this.startAng) + this.startAng;
    }



    // create a circular control
    // x, y is the center pos;
    // min max is the min max values
    // r1 r2 are inner and outer radius
    // ctx is the canvas context to draw to
    // mouse is the mouse object. This is a custom mouse object provided 
    //       in the demo.

    function createCircularControl(x,y,min,max,r1,r2,ctx,mouse){
        var s, fontSize;
        s = Math.min(r1,r2);
        fontSize = Math.ceil(s/2);            
        var control = {
            raw : 0,                    // the raw angle to draw the control handle ar
            floatingRaw : 0,            // if the actuale value floats independent of control position
            lastAng : 0,
            x : x,                      // center of control
            y : y,
            min : min,                  // min and max values 
            max : max, 
            value : 0,                  // value of control
            floatingValue : 0,
            startAng : -Math.PI/2,      // start angle
            endAng : Math.PI * (3/2),   // end angle
            radius1 : r1,               // inner and outer angles
            radius2 : r2, 
            border : 1,                 // border radius
            colour : "white",           // inner colour
            borderColour : "black",     // border colour
            lineColour : "#5AF",
            lineInnerColour : "#5AF",
            font : fontSize + "px Arial Black",  // font for center display
            handleSize : 1.5,           // handle size aas ratio to control width
            floating : false,
            draw : drawCirControl,      // function to draw control
            ctx : ctx,                  // get the context to draw to 
            mouse : mouse,              // set the mouse
            id : mouse.getInterfaceId(), // get an ID for this control
            update : updateCircularControl,  // updates the control
            setFloatingValue : setCirciularFloatingValue,
        }
        return control;
    }


    // create the controls
    var cont = createCircularControl(w/2, h/2, 0, 100, ix*5, ix*6, ctx, mouse);
    var cont1 = createCircularControl(w/6, h/4, 0, 1000, ix*2, ix*3, ctx, mouse);
    var cont2 = createCircularControl(w - w/6, h/4, 0, 1000, ix*2, ix*3, ctx, mouse);

    // set up top left control extra attributes
    // It has 10 rotations between min and max
    cont1.startAng =  -Math.PI/2;
    cont1.endAng =  -Math.PI/2 + PI2 * 10;
    cont1.handleSize = 1.0;
    cont1.lineInnerColour = "#8C5";


    // set up top left control extra attributes
    cont2.startAng =  0;
    cont2.endAng =  PI2 * 5;
    cont2.handleSize = 1.5;
    cont2.lineInnerColour = "#C85";
    cont2.colour = "black";
    cont2.borderColour = "Green";
    cont2.border = 3;
    cont2.floating = true;
    var fValue = 0;
    var fdValue = 0



    // Updates all 
    function update(){
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        fdValue += (cont2.value - fValue) * 0.01;
        fdValue *=  0.6;
        fValue += fdValue;
        cont2.setFloatingValue(fValue);
        cont.update();
        cont1.update();
        cont2.update();
        cont.draw();
        cont1.draw();
        cont2.draw();
        if(!STOP){
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }else{
            var canv = document.getElementById("canv");
            if(canv !== null){
                document.body.removeChild(canv);
            }            
            STOP = false;
        }
        mouse.frameEnd();
        
    }

    update();
    
}
var STOP = false;
function resizeEvent(){
    var waitForStopped = function(){
        if(!STOP){  // wait for stop to return to false
            demo();
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(waitForStopped,200);
    }
    STOP = true;
    setTimeout(waitForStopped,100);
}
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeEvent);
demo();
```